Movie with guy putting up hidden cameras in woman's house
I just can't seem to remember what this movie's called.
All I remember is that it's from around 2000-2009.
The bad guy puts up surveillance cameras in a woman's house, he becomes friends with her, helps her carry grocery bags etc.
Apparently he kicks her husband off of a horse too...
EDIT: Well, it's an English speaking movie, the husband of the family works with computers somehow, and the bad guy wants his help to steal some money. He installs some cameras in the family's home which the police then finds.
It's a thriller/drama.

That last sentence was hilarious! Can you provide more details about the movie such as language, genre (drama, horror, etc), describe a few more scenes or possibly describe the characters .

Tt's an English speaking movie, the husband of the family works with computers somehow, and the bad guy wants his help to steal some money. He installs some cameras in the family's home which the police then finds.
It's thriller/drama

Was it Firewall? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0408345/?ref_=nv_sr_1

No it's not Firewall, a friend thought so too

Where does he want to steal money from and how does he propose it gets done?

I know this isn't it, but this movie reminds me of Sliver (1993) (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108162/?ref_=nv_sr_1), with Sharon Stone and William Baldwin, where William's character had lots of cameras spying on everyone of the building, specially Sharon's character.

I think the movie you mean is Sliver.

Carly Norris is a book editor living in New York City who moves into the Sliver apartment building. In the apartment building, Carly meets two of her new neighbors, author Jack Lansford who writes thriller novels and Zeke Hawkins, the handsome owner of the apartment building. Carly finds that some of the women living in the apartment building have been murdered and the police suspect that there is a serial killer in the apartment building. Carly has a passionate and seductive love affair with Zeke, unaware Zeke has secretly wired the apartment building with hidden cameras and he has been watching the lives of each tenant living in the apartment building including Carly. Carly begins to suspect Zeke or Jack may be the serial killer responsible for the murders in the apartment building and she may be the killer's next victim. 


Welcome to Movies & TV. Please don't copy text from external sites without proper attribution and quoting markup.

the movie is Alone with Her (2006):

Invasion of privacy and domestic spying take on terrifying meaning in
  this unsettling tale of voyeurism. A young man has a secret obsession
  for a beautiful woman. By planting hidden cameras and listening
  devices in her home, he learns her most intimate secrets in order to
  manipulate her into a relationship that she innocently permits. Shot
  entirely through hidden cameras, including a "body cam," Alone With
  Her takes the audience to an extreme level of voyeuristic intimacy,
  exploiting both our fear of being watched and our compulsion to watch.


No it's not that one either, that was my first guess :/

It could be My Neighbor's Secret staring Nicholas Brendon.
Here the movie's page on wikipedia that include the whole plot.
The short plot from IMDB : 

A husband and wife begin to suspect that their newly widowed neighbor may have a serious dark side. Starring Nicholas Brendon.


Is this Hostage? In Hostage they are trying to steal a specific video tape that had privileged information. Ben Foster plays a bad guy who burns the house down with molotov cocktails

No sorry it's not Hostage :/

The Name of the movie is The Resident

When a young doctor suspects she may not be alone in her new Brooklyn
  loft, she learns that her landlord has formed a frightening obsession
  with her.


Could you provide some justification that this is the proper response over the number of others already submitted?
